c# delete zip file after unzip, need to check unzip done?
(WPF C# program)

I want to unzip a File.zip to some dir, and delete the File.zip after that, need I check if done before deleting (assume unzip works but slow).
like it, when I copy some files to some dir, and operate after that, do I need to check if the copy(assume it is slow too) is done befor post-operating?

System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(File.zip, some_dir, true);
// need to check if unzip is done here (assume it works slow)
File.Delete(File.zip);


If it were not done, won't you get an Exception ? Why does the "slow" part is important ? It does not look like an asynchronous method.

you can.. enumerate the zip entries right? then you can loop on each files and make sure all of them are extracted. though ExtraactToDirectory is a synchronous method, it will only continue to your next code once its completed.

Firstly, ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory() will only return after the files are extracted, so you don't have to worry about extraction being slow or fast.
Secondly you must wrap it in a try-catch so that if there is any failure you will come to know. Sample code:
try
{
  System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(File.zip, some_dir, true);
  // need to check if unzip is done here (assume it works slow)
  File.Delete(File.zip);
} 
catch(Exception ex)
{
  // extraction or some other issue
}

Finally if for some weird reason (file I/O overlap or something) your files are not ready, then best would be to put a sleep:
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); // 1 second sleep


You can just use await and it will make sure that the task is finished before moving in the code
Read more about asynchronous programming
private async void UnzipAndDeleteFile(string zipPath, string extractPath)
{
    try
    {
        await Task.Run(() => ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath, true));

        if (File.Exists(zipPath))
        {
            File.Delete(zipPath);
        }

        MessageBox.Show("File unzipped and deleted successfully.");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
    }
}

